# How to publish message on Facebook fan/business page?

Tags: facebook, gwt

I want to publish message on Facebook's fan page using JAVA/GWT API. 
Any one know any API to do this in GWT?
I am trying it with facebook4gwt. 
But don't know TemplateBundleId in facebook, which is needed for publishing message on wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gwt-facebook](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/) project adds Facebook API methods to GWT, but doesn't appear to have any wall-posting methods listed in its [currently-supported API methods](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/wiki/Facebook_API_Methods). You could probably take a look at the source and add this feature though, it would probably just be an addition to [FacebookApi](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/source/browse/trunk/GwittIt/src/com/gwittit/client/facebook/FacebookApi.java?r=308) (see [this diff](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/source/diff?format=side&path=/trunk/GwittIt/src/com/gwittit/client/facebook/FacebookApi.java&r=298&spec=svn298) which added the `comment_add` feature.